# render through python bpy.ops.render.render() is slow on saving image

Tags: python, rendering, animation

Whenever I use bpy.ops.render.render() function to render my animation it works but sometimes it stuck at saving an image to a disk. I know that because in the console i see this ' Time: 00:14.32 (Saving: 06:05.32). Why does it happen?
I also noticed that when I press 'CTRL+C' to cancel the operation sometimes it gets unstuck and shows that next line rendering and proceeded rendering further. is it internal blender communication with hardware issue or its a software issue?